# When we run the application, the Signup page displays the following error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mern

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
    
    const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        backgroundColor: "background-basic-color-1",
      },
      headerContainer: {
        minHeight: 216,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        paddingTop: 24,
        paddingBottom: 44,
      },
      signUpContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 32,
      },
      socialAuthContainer: {
        marginTop: 24,
      },
      socialAuthButtonsContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
      },
      socialAuthHintText: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        marginBottom: 16,
      },
      formContainer: {
        marginTop: 48,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
      },
      evaButton: {
        maxWidth: 72,
        paddingHorizontal: 0,
      },
      signInLabel: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      signInButton: {
        flexDirection: "row-reverse",
        paddingHorizontal: 0,
        width: 150,
        left: 175,
      },
      signUpButton: {
        marginVertical: 24,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
      },
      orContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginHorizontal: 16,
        marginTop: 52,
      },
      divider: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      orLabel: {
        marginHorizontal: 8,
      },
      emailSignLabel: {
        alignSelf: "center",
        marginTop: 8,
      },
      formInput: {
        marginTop: 16,
      },
      termsCheckBox: {
        marginTop: 20,
      },
      termsCheckBoxText: {
        fontSize: 11,
        lineHeight: 14,
        color: "text-hint-color",
        marginLeft: 10,
      },
      picker: {
        marginVertical: 30,
        width: 300,
        padding: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#666",
      },
      icon: {
        position: 'absolute', 
        right: 50, 
        bottom: 270,
         
    }
    });
    export default Styles;
 

a
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Alert,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView,
    ToastAndroid,
} from "react-native";
import { Button, Input, Text, Layout } from "@ui-kitten/components";
import { sendRegistrationOtp } from "../../Services/User";
import { verifyPhone } from "../../Services/User";
import Styles from "./RegFormStyle";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
const Reg_form = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [FirstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
    const [LastName, setLastName] = useState("");
    const [Address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [CNIC, setCNIC] = useState("");
    const [Phone_no, setPhone_no] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");

    const [FirstNameValidError, setFirstNameValidError] = useState("");
    const [LastNameValidError, setLastNameValidError] = useState("");
    const [AddressValidError, setAddressValidError] = useState("");
    const [CNICValidError, setCNICValidError] = useState("");
    const [EmailValidError, setEmailValidError] = useState("");
    const [PhoneValidError, setPhoneValidError] = useState("");
    const [PasswordValidError, setPasswordValidError] = useState("");

    const submit = () => {
        FirstNamevalidate(FirstName);
        LastNamevalidate(LastName);
        Addressvalidate(Address);
        CNICvalidate(CNIC);
        emailvalidate(Email);
        phonevalidate(Phone_no);
        passwordvalidate(password);

        if (
            FirstName == "" ||
            LastName == "" ||
            Address == "" ||
            CNIC == "" ||
            Phone_no == "" ||
            Email == "" ||
            password == ""
        ) {
            ToastAndroid.show("Please Fill All Fields", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        }
        if (
            FirstName != "" &&
            LastName != "" &&
            Address != "" &&
            CNIC != "" &&
            Phone_no != "" &&
            password != "" &&
            FirstNameValidError == "" &&
            LastNameValidError == "" &&
            AddressValidError == "" &&
            CNICValidError == "" &&
            PhoneValidError == "" &&
            PasswordValidError == ""
        ) {
            verifyPhone(Phone_no).then((response) => {
                if (!response) {
                    ToastAndroid.show("Phone Number already exists", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                } else {
                    sendRegistrationOtp(Email).then((response) => {
                        if (response) {
                            ToastAndroid.show("Email Sent !", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                            navigation.navigate("Verification", {
                                FirstName: FirstName,
                                LastName: LastName,
                                Address: Address,
                                CNIC: CNIC,
                                Email: Email,
                                Phone_no: Phone_no,
                                password: password,
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
    const FirstNamevalidate = (FirstName) => {
        const re = /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/;
        if (re.test(FirstName) === false) {
          setFirstNameValidError("Enter valid name (First letter capitalized, rest small or capitalized)");
        } else {
          setFirstNameValidError("");
        }
      };

      const LastNamevalidate = (LastName) => {
        const re = /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$/;
        if (re.test(LastName) === false) {
          setLastNameValidError("Enter valid name (First letter capitalized, rest small or capitalized)");
        } else {
          setLastNameValidError("");
        }
      };

      const Addressvalidate = (Address) => {
        const re = /^([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ./#,-]*\s)*[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ./#,-]*$/;
        if (re.test(Address) === false) {
          setAddressValidError("Enter valid address (First letter of each word capitalized, rest small or capitalized)");
        } else {
          setAddressValidError("");
        }
      };
      const CNICvalidate = (CNIC) => {
        const re = /^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]$/;
        if (re.test(CNIC) === false) {
          setCNICValidError("Enter Valid CNIC Number (Format: xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x)");
        } else {
          setCNICValidError("");
        }
      };

      const emailvalidate = (Email) => {
        const reg = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=.?^_`{|}~-]+@gmail\.com$/;
        if (reg.test(Email) === false) {
          setEmailValidError("Enter a valid gmail address");
        } else {
          setEmailValidError("");
        }
      };

    const phonevalidate = (Phone_no) => {
        const regular = /^[0-9]*$/;
        if (regular.test(Phone_no) === false) {
            setPhoneValidError("Enter Valid Phone Number(Max Length 11)");
        }
        if (Phone_no.length < 11) {
            setPhoneValidError("Phone number should be 11 digits");
        } else {
            setPhoneValidError("");
        }
    };
    const passwordvalidate = (password) => {
        const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/;
        if (regex.test(password) === false) {
          setPasswordValidError("Password must be 8 characters long and include at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character");
        } else {
          setPasswordValidError("");
        }
      };      

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
            <ScrollView style={{ height: "100%" }}>
                <Layout style={[Styles.container, Styles.formContainer]}>
                    {/*  */}
                    <Button
                        style={Styles.signInButton}
                        // appearance="ghost"
                        status="control"
                        size="giant"
                        accessoryLeft={<Icon name="arrow-forward" size={15} />}
                        onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate("Log In");
                        }}
                    >
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
                    <Input
                        placeholder="Muhammad"
                        label="FIRST NAME"
                        value={FirstName}
                        onChangeText={(e) => {
                            setFirstName(e);
                            FirstNamevalidate(e);
                        }}
                    />
                    {FirstNameValidError ? (
                        <Text style={{ color: "red", alignSelf: "center" }}>
                            {FirstNameValidError}
                        </Text>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                    <Input
                        style={Styles.formInput}
                        placeholder="Waleed"
                        label="LAST NAME"
                        value={LastName}
                        onChangeText={(e) => {
                            setLastName(e);
                            LastNamevalidate(e);
                        }}
                    ></Input>
                    {LastNameValidError ? (
                        <Text style={{ color: "red", alignSelf: "center" }}>
                            {LastNameValidError}
                        </Text>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                    <Input
                        style={Styles.formInput}
                        placeholder="House No.176-C,Street No.08,Sector No. G-6"
                        label="ADDRESS"
                        value={Address}
                        onChangeText = {(e) => {
                            setAddress(e);
                            Addressvalidate(e);
                        }}
                    ></Input>
                    {AddressValidError ? (
                        <Text style={{ color: "red", alignSelf: "center" }}>
                            {AddressValidError}
                        </Text>
                    ):(
                        <></>
                    )
                    }
                    <Input
                        style={Styles.formInput}
                        placeholder="61101-*******-*"
                        label="CNIC"
                        value={CNIC}
                        onChangeText = {(e) => {
                            setCNIC(e);
                            CNICvalidate(e);
                        }}
                    ></Input>
                    {CNICValidError ? (
                        <Text style={{ color: "red", alignSelf: "center" }}>
                            {CNICValidError}
                        </Text>
                    ):(
                        <></>
                    )
                    }
                    <Input
                        style={Styles.formInput}
                        placeholder="muhammadwaleedashfaq2020@gmail.com"
                        label="EMAIL"
                        value={Email}
                        onChangeText={(e) => {
                            setEmail(e);
                            emailvalidate(e);
                        }}
                    ></Input>
                    {EmailValidError ? (
                        <Text style={{ color: "red", alignSelf: "center" }}>
                            {EmailValidError}
                        </Text>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                    <Input
                        style={Styles.formInput}
                        placeholder="0332XXXXXXX"
                        label="PHONE NUMBER"
                        value={Phone_no}
                        minValue={11}
                        keyboardType="number-pad"
                        maxLength={11}
                        onChangeText={(e) => {
                            setPhone_no(e);
                            phonevalidate(e);
                        }}
                    ></Input>
                    {PhoneValidError ? (
                        <Text style={{ color: "red", alignSelf: "center" }}>
                            {PhoneValidError}
                        </Text>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                    <Input
                        style={Styles.formInput}
                        placeholder="password"
                        label="PASSWORD"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        value={password}
                        onChangeText={(e) => {
                            setPassword(e);
                            passwordvalidate(e);
                        }}
                    ></Input>
                    {PasswordValidError ? (
                        <Text style={{ color: "red", alignSelf: "center" }}>
                            {PasswordValidError}
                        </Text>
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
                    <View>
                        <Button
                            style={Styles.signUpButton}
                            Layout={Styles.btn}
                            onPress={() => {
                                submit();
                            }}
                        >
                            Register
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </Layout>
            </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
};
export default Reg_form;
```

*The error is: ERROR Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key tintColor supplied to Text.
I think the problem is in the styling sheet, which we import during signup. The warning mentioned (Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key tintColor supplied to Text.) is indeed related to a styling issue. It's likely caused by the use of the tintColor property in the styles of the Text component.

Comment: search the 'tintColor' then find what make your error

Comment: The color tint does not exist in the style sheet, however it displays an error.

Comment: may it's from the library, you need to search in total project

Comment: I'm utilizing the Eva Design Library. but there is an issue in this code. nowhere else

Comment: did you got this link from the error look like this: `http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.vedaxlink&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:60456:106`? Open it's from chorme, copy all code, then paste into somwhere, find exactyle the line 60456, it's will show more information